# Auto incremental variable name eclipse

Tags: eclipse

Is there a way in eclipse to auto-increment each variable name?

For example

```
int mInt;
int mInt2;
int mInt3;
int mInt4;
```

and etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Chances are good that if you need that many similarly-named variables, that you'd be better off with a different data structure, like an array.

Comment: Probably better off as a comment, not an answer, but I agree.

Comment: I disagree - if that's the answer, then it's appropriate.  Armchair quarterbacking like this is not constructive, in my opinion.

Comment: I'm making Static textures for an animation. so for an example of a ball. Texture ball1, Texture ball2, Texture ball3, Texture ball4, etc

Comment: I could envision a List<Texture> if that's the case.